# Ordenar campo DateTime apenas pela parte Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, classificação

Eu tenho uma propriedade de uma entidade que é do tipo `DateTime?` e no SQL Server é do tipo `datetime` também. Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que ordene pela data, porém sem considerar a hora, pois nessa view específica não irá mostrar a hora. Depois ordenar por código.

Fazer duas ordenações eu consigo com `ThenBy`, não sei como ignorar a hora.

```
var query = contexto.Contas.OrderBy(c => c.Data).ThenBy(c => c.Codigo);
```

Suponha esses dados

> 001 | 22/12/2016 13:25
>
> 002 | 22/12/2016 11:25
>
> 003 | 22/12/2016 12:25

---

Hoje é exibido assim:

> 002 | 22/12/2016
>
> 003 | 22/12/2016
>
> 001 | 22/12/2016

---

Mas deveria ser assim:

> 001 22/12/2016
>
> 002 22/12/2016
>
> 003 22/12/2016

Comment: Tive um caso semelhante usando o `nHibernate`, resolvi fazendo isto `...OrderBy(c => c.Data.HasValue ?  c.Data.Date : ((DateTime?)null)))`,

Comment: Complementando o que o @MarcoGiovanni falou. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6121309/2957607

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Entity Framework 6

Use [**`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
contexto.Contas.OrderBy(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Data)).ThenBy(c => c.Codigo);
```

#### Entity Framework <= 5

Use [**`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
contexto.Contas.OrderBy(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Data)).ThenBy(c => c.Codigo);
```

Estas funções irão remover a parte da hora, considerando somente a data.

---

Na prática, isso é a mesma coisa que usar **`c.Data.Date`**. A questão é que o Entity Framework não consegue "converter" este `c.Data.Date` para uma *query* válida.

Usando o `.ToList()`, você acaba trazendo todos os dados para a memória e eles serão ordenados na aplicação. Se você souber bem o que está fazendo, pode ser uma alternativa válida, mas eu (praticamente) sempre acho melhor trazer os dados já ordenados.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria você dar um `ToList` antes de ordenar, ficando assim

```
var query = contexto.Contas.ToList().OrderBy(c => c.Data.Date).ThenBy(c => c.Codigo);
```

Comment: E trazer todos os dados pra memória antes de ordenar?

Comment: Não é uma boa solução, mas funcionária.